# Can anyone recommend a payment gateway for a charity website?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

Are there payment gateways that only take a percentage of whatever money is paid, but that have a very small up-front startup fee?

I want to set up a payment gateway for a charity.

By the way - is there any harm in just accepting donations through paypal and avoiding the whole payment gateway hassle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many opensource projects use paypal for donations, I guess there is no problem with that.

Comment: I just found PayPal Donations, which seems good, and is already used by several other charities, so I guess I'll go with that for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

For a start up I recommend Paypal Pro. You can use the Paypal Pro solution to create an online donation form. With that your donors can pay with any card type, not just Paypal. 
If you choose something else, I recommend you have a month to month contract- as a start up you don't know what the future holds.

Answer (score 0):

[Network For Good](https://www.groundspring.org/services/donatenow.cfm) seems like a good bet. No startup fee and $30/mo + 3%/transactions fee. The company itself is a nonprofit, too.

For other suggestions...

http://nonprofit.about.com/od/faqsfundraising/f/creditcards.htm

Answer (score 0):

Paypal doesn't charge charities the fees that other payment gateways will, so this is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Some companies are beginning to provide donation software and payments includes at no cost except a per item fee. Global Cloud and Simply Easier Payments are some examples.  Get all the bells and whistles at no extra cost other than the same processing fee as PayPal.